# Reading a "ParseFile" using java

Tags: java, android, file, parse-platform

I have retrieved a "ParseFile" from "parse.com".However,I am not able to figure out a proper method to read that "ParseFile" .I tried to read the parseFile using  Java's "BufferReader" only to end up in vain.

Below posted is my code

```
 final ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("TestObject");
    query.getInBackground("xxxxxxxxx", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                try {
                    ParseFile parseFile=object.getParseFile("file");
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(String.valueOf(parseFile)));
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = br.readLine();
                    while (line != null) {
                        sb.append(line);
                        sb.append("\n");
                        line = br.readLine();

                    }
                    System.out.println("exact values"+sb.toString());
                    br.close(); }
                catch (Exception e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }


            } else {
                System.out.println("bye!!");
            }
        }
    });
```

Below posted is my StackTrace:

```
10-14 00:10:33.178  18300-18300/? W/System.err﹕       
java.io.FileNotFoundException:  
com.parse.ParseFile@328cdd84: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or  
directory)
10-14 00:10:33.178  18300-18300/? W/System.err﹕ at 
libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
10-14 00:10:33.178  18300-18300/? W/System.err﹕ at java.io.FileInputStream. 
<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
10-14 00:10:33.178  18300-18300/? W/System.err﹕ at java.io.FileInputStream.  
<init>(FileInputStream.java:105)
10-14 00:10:33.178  18300-18300/? W/System.err﹕ at java.io.FileReader.<init>  
(FileReader.java:66)
```

The line FilenotFound Exception is pointing to:

```
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(String.valueOf(parseFile)));
```

Any Suggestions would be highly helpful.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing the string of the Object parseFile, not a File to the FileReader.

Change the line

```
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(String.valueOf(parseFile)));
```

to

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(parseFile.getFile()));
```